# Unable to use a new ConnectionStrings created with entity Builder

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, ado.net

In my app.config file I have this default connctionString named DBEntities1 which has **read-only** access (because of the user id: **appUser**) on the database:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBModel1.csdl|res://*/DBModel1.ssdl|res://*/DBModel1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=appUser;password=pass;database=db&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

but in my program, I tried to **change user id and password** by modifying and reusing the same connectionstring to get **full access** on the database like this:

```c#
ConnectionStringSettings settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBEntities1"];
EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(settings.ToString());
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString);

sqlBuilder.UserID = "sosso";
sqlBuilder.Password = "password";
entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ToString();
String newConnectioStrings = entityBuilder.ToString();

using(EntityConnection connection = new EntityConnection(newConnectionStrings))
{
        connection.Open();

        DBEntities1 context = new DBEntities1();
        client c = new client();

        c.table_client = 1;
        c.idClient = 0;

        context.client.Add(c);
        context.SaveChanges();
        connection.Close();
}
```

but it seems that the program is still using the old connectionStrings with the old user id and returns an error in the context.SaveChanges(); method saying :

MySqlException: The 'INSERT' command is forbidden to the user: **'appUser'** @ '@ localhost' on the 'client' table.

**PLEASE** how can i make the program use the new connectionStrings ??????